# Controller method without PathVariable removes all entitites

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I would like that method:

```
@DeleteMapping("/todos/{id}")
public ResponseEntity deleteToDo(
        @PathVariable("id") Long itemId,
        Principal principal
) {
    ObjectNode jsonObject = mapper.createObjectNode();
    User currentUser = userService.findLoggedInUser(principal);
    if (toDoItemService.toDoExists(itemId)) {
        ToDoItem toDoFromDb = toDoItemService.getToDoItemById(itemId);
        if (toDoItemService.canUserAccessToDo(toDoFromDb, currentUser)) {
                toDoItemService.deleteToDo(itemId);
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        } else {
            jsonObject.put("status", "You can only delete your ToDos");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(jsonObject, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }
    } else {
        jsonObject.put("status", "ToDo with that ID doesn't exist.");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(jsonObject, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

to only work when there is {id} in the url. Right now when I do DELETE @ /todos/ it removes all ToDos from the db - I don't know why because after this line `if (toDoItemService.toDoExists(itemId))` returns false it should just return "ToDo with that ID doesn't exist" but instead it removes all ToDos.

Here is **toDoExists** method:

```
 public boolean toDoExists(Long id) {
    if (toDoItemRepository.findOne(id) != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

How can I fix it? I want user to only access DELETE @ /todos/{id} and if he goes to /todos/ then he gets 'method not allowed' or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather put this in the comments but I don't have enough rep to comment :(

You wouldn't happen to have another delete method (that does not have a path variable) that deletes all the todos ?
Hence when you dont pass the the path variable it hits that method instead ?
eg

```
@DeleteMapping("/todos")
public ResponseEntity deleteTodos(){ service.deleteAll(); return... }
```